# Find files in one directory not in another

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, filesystems

Are there any Linux/Unix tools which find all the files in one directory not present in another? Basically I'm looking for diff which works on the output of ls.

Short and sweet scripts are also appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

`diff` does this already:

```
diff dir1 dir2
```

Example output:

```
Only in dir1: some_file.txt
Only in dir1: some_other_file.txt
Only in dir2: third_file.txt
```

Comment: This is good. One gripe: diff is actually running on each of the files that are in both. Is there an obscure option to just run against file names (I may have missed it)? Otherwise, I suggest `diff dir1 dir2 | grep "Only"`

Comment: wow this just save me many minutes of bash scripting thanks

Answer (score 14):

Bash:

```
diff <(cd dir1; ls) <(cd dir2; ls)
```

Compare only the filenames - not the contents of the files.

Comment: Also ksh and zsh.

Comment: use rsync for sync dirs

Comment: Do not parse `ls`, use `find` instead!

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica: This isn't an example of parsing `ls` since it's only getting a list of files and not looking at fields in output such as `ls -l`. It's also not parsing the names themselves so special characters aren't a problem except for newlines. But diff is going to treat parts of file names surrounding newlines separately anyway (even [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/177012/1293) with `grep Only` fails in this regard).

Comment: can this be made to be recursive?

Comment: @majorgear: These answers offer ways to do that: [with `--brief`](https://serverfault.com/a/839992/1293) or [with `find`](https://serverfault.com/a/871967/1293) (use `find .` if on a Mac).

Answer (score 4):

Like people told you here, you can use DIFF in various usage variations. Or you just use `dirdiff` instead, which is meant for what you're trying! :-)

But if you want to keep some directories in sync then you really should take a look on `rsync`.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting to do this through all sub directories as well, a good way to do it is:

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/
```

I prefer using brief, but you can leave that out if you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but found WAY more files than I anticipated. Is there any way to copy the files found in `dir2/` to a new folder? `dir3/`

Answer (score 1):

`for i in $(ls -1 directory1); do if (test -f directory2/$i) then echo $i; fi; done`

Answer (score 1):

Dennis Williamson had a [good answer](https://serverfault.com/a/177034/434048), but I needed to do this recursively. GNU findutils 4.7.0 doesn't sort its output, so here's what I used

```
diff <(cd $dir1; find | sort) <(cd $dir2; find | sort)
```

To do this only one way, and produce a list of files, I used this:

```
diff <(cd $dir1; find | sort) <(cd $dir2; find | sort) \
| grep '< ./' | sed "s,< ./,$dir1/,"
```

For this to work properly, neither $dir1 nor $dir2 should include the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

This works..

```
ls -a1 /dir1 | sort > /tmp/1
ls -a1 /dir2 | sort > /tmp/2
diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2
```

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
find /dir/A -printf "%P" | while read f; do
  if [ ! -e "/dir/B/$f" ]; then
    echo $f
  fi
done
```